# Documentation on Kernel variables

Tags: ubuntu, ip, kernel, iptables, net

I was wondering if some one can point to some good documentation which can give me detailed information about some kernel variable. I am right now mostly interested in the following variables / parameters and how it effects the system and how to decide their optimum values

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.ip_conntrack_max = 231072
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal = 0
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_loose = 3
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_log_invalid = 0
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 180
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_checksum = 1
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_buckets = 8192
fs.file-max = 98304
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of them are documented in the Documentation folder in the kernel source. Some of them are only in the comments in the kernel source code.